# Hastings' "two" definitions of trivial mixed states

Tags: condensed-matter, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator, topological-order

In https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.6026 (Definition 3), Hastings defines a density matrix $\rho$ in Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ to be trivial if one can tensor in additional degrees of freedom $\mathcal{K}$ such that $\rho = \text{Tr}_\mathcal{K}(U \rho_{cl}U^\dagger)$, where $U$ is a low-depth local unitary cirtcuit and $\rho_{cl}$ is a convex sum product states.

On the other hand, he also mentions (right after Definition 3) that the aforementioned definition is equivalent to saying that $\rho$ is trivial if it can be written as a convex sum of pure states, where each of them is a short-ranged entangled (SRE) state, i.e., a state that can be prapered by applying a low-depth local unitary circuit to some product state.

While both definitions make sense to me, is it obvious to see that they are equivalent?
For example, consider a density matrix $\rho$ that can be purified as a SRE state $U |\psi_0\rangle$, with $U$ a low-depth local unitary and $|\psi_0\rangle = \otimes_i |0\rangle_i$ a product state in the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H} \otimes \mathcal{K}$. One can immediately see that $\rho$ satisfies Hastings' first definition by chosing $\rho_{cl} = |\psi_0\rangle \langle \psi_0|$. However, how can one show that $\rho = \text{Tr}_K(U|\psi_0\rangle \langle \psi_0|U^\dagger)$ can be written as a convex sum of SRE states? To put it another way, how to show that the partial trace of a SRE pure state can be written as a convex sum of SRE states?

Comment: I guess it depends on how specifically the degrees of freedom are tensored in/traced out.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Indeed, the degrees of freedom that are tensored in/traced out are defined on each site in the paper. For example, if the standard purification for $\rho$, i.e., $|\rho^{1/2}\rangle \equiv \rho^{1/2} \otimes I |\Phi\rangle$ with $|\Phi\rangle$ the tensor product of maximally entangled pairs on all the sites , is trivial, I believe it satisfies Hastings' first defition of trivial mixed states. 
But it is still unclear to me how to show that $\rho$ can be written as a convex sum of SRE states given $|\rho^{1/2}\rangle$ is trivial.

Comment: Also, the paper mentions that those definitions are equivalent if we allow $\rho_{cl}$ and $\mathcal{K}$ to be unbounded, so I suspect the second definition (convex sum of SRE states) is stricter than the first. But I don't know how to utilize the condition that $\rho_{cl}$ and $\mathcal{K}$ are unbounded to show their equivalence.